# SSRS Casting makes Report Run Slow

Tags: reporting-services, expression, sumifs, iif-function

I have seen several posts about the sum if error, but I couldn't find anything quite like this. I am working on a report that has about 9 textboxes with the expressions listed below (changed up a lil per textbox).

Example 1 - this gives the #Error when the report is rendered

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!RATING.value >= 6, (Fields!NetBal.Value), 0))
```

Example2 - this makes the report rendering extremely slow (even if I remove all but 1 of these textboxes with this expression, it takes forever)

```
=Sum(IIF(FIELDS!RATING.Value >= 6, CDBL(Fields!NetBal.Value), CDBL(0)))
```

Comment: Sorry I am so late responding, there are no Null's in NetBal, but there are Nulls in the Rating field. This is the weirdest thing, and I have asked around on multiple boards to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried this:=SUM(IIF(Fields!RATING.value >= 6, (Fields!NetBal.Value), 0.0))

Comment: Yep, it turns all of my True values to #Error except for the ones that don't meet the criteria.

Comment: Corrections: Yep, it turns all of my True values to #Error.

Comment: I only get this one warning: [rsAggregateOfMixedDataTypes] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox44.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses an aggregate function on data of varying data types.  Aggregate functions other than First, Last, Previous, Count, and CountDistinct can only aggregate data of a single data type.

Comment: What is the datatype of NetBal?  Try casting the 0 as the same datatype.

Comment: NetBal is numeric(17,2) with no Null values.

Comment: Assuming that Textbox44 is the one with the #Error, the message is saying you have to make it so that only one possible datatype can be returned inside the SUM() function.  What if you try this:  =SUM(Cdbl(IIF(Fields!RATING.value >= 6, (Fields!NetBal.Value), 0)))    Although honestly I'm surprised that changing 0 to 0.0 doesn't fix it.  Does the error message change when you try it?

Comment: The error message doesn't change. I was trying to figure out why the datatype would be different (as the warning suggest), unless it is looking at the 0.00 that NetBal could be when trying to sum it. I am going to try your suggestion now.

Comment: Ok, I tried that, I got the proper values, but it literally takes about 7 minutes to render it. There are only about 18k records, I don't know what to make of this. I even asked the DBA, we were both stumped.

Comment: No idea why it's so slow, but can you move that logic into your stored procedure, so you can just map the textbox to a simple value?  Might be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a typo?
In your first formula the first 'value' is written in lower case where it probably should be 'Value'.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!RATING.value >= 6, (Fields!NetBal.Value), 0))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, let me try that out. I will let you know! Thanks!